# Should a domain be modularised based on aggregates (1 module per aggregate)?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, module, domain-driven-design

Thinking that "MODULE structures and names often reflect much earlier forms of the model
than the classes do". 
What is the best practice regarding domain modularisation?

For Example: A simple domain for cars engines and customers of engines and cars.

Aggregate 1: Engine;

Aggregate 2: Car with the following contained objects Wheel, Position, Tire;

Aggregate 3: Customer;

Should the domain be modularised based on the aggregate roots? That is, the car module contains the corespondent aggregate with factories repositories etc, customer module the corespondent aggregate and so on.

Or should it be modularised based on some other factors? And if yes, is it a good thing to scatter aggregate objects in different modules?

For further clarification, here is my response to MikeSW's comment:

Knowing that the domain might evolve in time, some Agile thought should be implemented in the domain. This leads to modularisation. I'm novice regarding how Agile development works also not very experienced with DDD. But I know modularisation should follow some patterns (this is where my expression "best practice" come from).

For starter it's not clear if an aggregate should really represent a chapter in a user story (of course it might). But there are some cases when it doesn't. So in this case should a module include parts of aggregates or whole aggregates (for domain sake)

Comment: There isn't a 'best' practice, everyone does how they see it fit for the app and their style

Comment: @MikeSW Knwoing that the domain might evolve in time , some agile thought should be implemented in the domain . This leads to modularisation . I'm novice regarding how agile development works also not very experienced with DDD . But i know modularisation should follow some patterns (this is where my expression "best practice" come from) . For starter it's not clear if an aggregate should really represent a chapter in a user story (ofcourse it might) . But there are some cases when it doesnt . So in this case should a module include parts of aggregates or whole aggregates (for domain sake) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some basic rules of building proper domain modules :

- Modules should contain one or more aggregates (aggregate objects should not be scatered on multiple modules);
- Modules should have high cohesion and low coupling (better if none) to the other modules . Try to make them independent from each other ;
- Put any events , factories , repositories, services in the module that contain the aggregates to which they are bound ;
- Modules should reflect the concerns of the domain and the naming should reflect the Ubiquitous Language .
- If some modules are coupled , try to make the dependency aciclic ;
- Build modules based on aggregates with high cohesion and based on the context in which they are used .
- If there may exist medium to highly coupled modules , create a parent module and put them inside .

So my final answer is NO , the modules should not be built based on aggregates (1 AR per module). But based on the domain concepts and based on the context in which coupled aggregates are used .

**Add a comment if you think my answer is invalid (for downvoters) :) . Still waiting for better pointers . If no other answer is submitted i will accept this one .**

Comment: So basically you say 1 Module == 1 Bounded context?

Comment: @DonZampano Yes. But there can be multilevel bounded context . For example a company has many departments . The company bounded context may have a loaner aggregate , shareholder aggregate etc . The company may have independent bounded contexts like accounting department , IT deppartment etc . It ultimately depends on the implementation , but yes , the bounded context is the main ideea for modularising the domain .